# Why does 100G Ethernet use FEC while Infiniband doesn't?

Tags: ethernet, networking

The 100G Ethernet physical layer signalling is moving to PAM4 and using Forward Error Correction (FEC) when the lane signalling rate is greater than 25 Gigabaud (Either 4 lanes x 25 or 2 x 50).

Infiniband EDR uses a signal rate of 25 Gigabaud (Gbd) also and from what I can see HDR uses a rate of 50 Gbd.  But Infiniband doesn't use FEC.

What is the difference in signalling that allows Infiniband (IB) to have the same signal rates but doesn't use FEC to reduce error rates.  Or does IB just accept higher bit error rates? (Or alternatively is there some other correction in higher layers that allows IB to get away with higher error rates at the physical layer).

Comment: What's the date on the Infiniband spec? IIRC it was developed before FEC at 25 G was available. Also, what's the maximum cable length for IB vs Ethernet?

Comment: If binary signaling, more power means stronger drive about a (central binary) threshold. 4 PAM cannot do that trivially.

Comment: @ThePhoton: IB using fibre optics supports up to 10km and Ethernet has an array of standards, some going 80km.  But at least some of them they use FEC with a maximum reach of less than 10km.

Comment: @ThePhoton, and unavailability of the technology could explain it, but then how does IB manage to operate at the high signal rates without FEC.  FEC is adding latency and if it is unnecessary then why use it (or is it a different trade off for latency vs BER being made?) - that's what I'm trying to understand.

Comment: You can do 25 Gbps over 10 km with a very expensive laser, or with a cheap laser and FEC. I don't know enough about Infiniband to say why they chose to go without FEC. Ethernet pretty much held off on defining a 25 Gbps per channel solution until chips capable of doing FEC at that rate were available.

Comment: FEC comes with a latency penalty on the receive side as the whole block needs to be present for decoding and correcting the errors. It's possible that the designers of IB did not want to pay this latency penalty.

Comment: I assume you are talking about some specific variant of 100G Ethernet over fiber. Some of which can reach 80km? There are many variants: multi wavelengths/multi fiber/PAM4/fiber types/power envelopes. You should be more specific on what are you trying to compare and the question would answer itself.

Comment: @alex.forencich, you have just reworded the question - of course FEC comes with a latency penalty (on transmit as well), and I doubt that Ethernet _wants_ to pay that latency penalty but they have to.  Why doesn't IB?

Comment: @EdgarBrown: Yes there are many variants, but even comparing similar maximum lengths between IB and Ethernet, the Ethernet has FEC and IB doesn't.  This despite similar baud rate, fibre and maximum distance. The question is why/how?

Comment: Well, it's entirely possible that latency is the only reason. IB is designed for HPC, so maybe they figured the latency hit was unacceptable. Maybe the Ethernet standards people were OK the extra latency as that meant they could make their links longer, as Ethernet tends to be used over relatively long distances. However, this is all speculation - I do not know what the precise decision making process was.